# Instantiate object at a specific location?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, instantiation, destroy

I am just trying to make a square object get destroyed and have a new one instantiated in it's place. What happens now is that the first object is destroyed, and the new one will appear. But it will always appear in the middle of the screen and not in it's parent transform that holds the script.
I have tried setting the vectors, using code to set the parent and a few other things but nothing works. Here, and thanks in advance!

```
public Transform RaisingBlock;
public GameObject lava1;
public GameObject raisedBlock1;
public GameObject loweredBlock1;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("MyEvent");
}

private IEnumerator MyEvent()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        Destroy(this.gameObject); 
        Instantiate(lava1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what programming language you are using here? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: This seems to have your answer:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97370/how-do-i-instantiate-a-prefab-to-a-specific-coordinate

Comment: Looks like C# to me. Where is this.gameObject instantiated? What I believe is happening is that this.gameObject is either inistantiated, or later given certain values for its properties. When you destroy that object, obviously it's now gone. But you Instantiate a new object with new values (perhaps default, even system default, values). What you need to do is instantiate the new object with the exact values the previously destroyed object had at destruction. You might consider any of the cloning patterns out there to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

When you destroy the gameObject, it gets deleted from the active screen. So its location will be lost as well. But the problem here is that you should state the location when you instantiate the lava1 object. Consider using one of the overloads of Instantiate to accomplish this:

```
Instantiate(lava1, this.gameObject.transform.position, 
            this.gameObject.transform.rotation);
```

Also, your coroutine stops because your script gets destroyed along with the gameObject.

Comment: Nope, I've tried all the solutions, and they all do the exact same thing, the object gets deleted, and then lava1 gets instantiated into the middle of the screen, no matter what.
I've tried:
Vector3 position = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);

GameObject newGameObject = Instantiate(GameObjectToInstantiate);

newGameObject.transform.position = position;

And
Instantiate(lava1, this.gameObject.transform.position, 
            this.gameObject.transform.rotation);

Comment: And
GameObject myRoadInstance =
            Instantiate(Resources.Load("road"),
            new Vector3(5, 5, 5),
            Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

But they all do the exact same thing, object reappears in the middle of the gameworld every time.

Comment: does your lava gameObject have a animation or some other similar component ? animations if not parented to a another parent game object could reset position also move the Destroy(this.gameObject) line after instantiate method call